# Using One Service to Stop Another

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services

I have written a windows service application whose purpose is to stop and later start another service.

I am getting this error when I try the stop the other service.

Failed in StopTheProcess Cannot stop CaseMixProcessManager service on computer '.'.System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The service cannot accept control messages at this time

I can see that the status of the service I am trying to stop is 4 for running. The user has the privileges to stop and start the service.

I still don't get what Harry is suggesting so I am posting the whole program as there is not that much to it. Perhaps Harry or someone else can suggest how to change it.

```
 Public Sub StartProcessing()

        Try


        ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.LogSource = "ServiceController"

        ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.WriteLog("Service Controller Started " & cGlobals.m_Version, EventLogEntryType.Information)
        m_StartHour = GetConfiguation("StartHour")
        m_StopHour = GetConfiguation("StopHour")
        m_ServiceName = GetConfiguation("ServiceName")

        m_Service = New ServiceProcess.ServiceController(m_ServiceName)


        If StartOrStop() = True Then
            WaitToStart()
        Else
            WaitToStop()
        End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.WriteLog("Failed in Start Processing " & ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try

    End Sub
    Private Function FigureNextTime(p_Hour As String) As Boolean
        Dim _TimeToRestart As DateTime
        Dim _TodayString As String
        Dim _RestartString As String
        Dim _NowTime As DateTime
        Dim _Result As Int32

        Try


            ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.WriteLog("FigureNextTime " & p_Hour, EventLogEntryType.Information)
            ' we need to restart the process automatically at a certain hour
            If p_Hour = "N" Then
                Return False
            End If

            If IsNumeric(p_Hour) = False Then
                Return False
            End If

            p_Hour = p_Hour & ":00:00"


            _TodayString = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today)

            _RestartString = _TodayString.Replace("12:00:00", p_Hour)

            _RestartString = _RestartString.Replace("AM", "")
            _TimeToRestart = Convert.ToDateTime(_RestartString)

            ' next compare the two dates see if the time has passed

            _NowTime = (DateTime.Now)
            _Result = DateTime.Compare(_NowTime, _TimeToRestart)

            If (_Result >= 0) Then
                ' we add one day to the restart time
                _TimeToRestart = _TimeToRestart.AddDays(1)

            End If

            m_MinutesDifference = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, _NowTime, _TimeToRestart)

            ' figure the millseconds until it's time to start the process

            m_MilliSeconds = m_MinutesDifference * 60000

            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.WriteLog("Failed in FigureNextTime " & ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
            Return False
        End Try


    End Function
    Private Function GetConfiguation(p_KeyName As String) As String


        Return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(p_KeyName)


    End Function

    Private Sub WaitToStart()

        Try


            ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.WriteLog("WaitToStart", EventLogEntryType.Information)

            If FigureNextTime(m_StartHour) = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If


            ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.WriteLog("Will start in  " & m_MinutesDifference & " Minutes", EventLogEntryType.Information)


            m_svcTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(m_MilliSeconds)

            ' Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
            AddHandler m_svcTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf StartTheProcess

            ' Set the Interval  
            m_svcTimer.Interval = m_MilliSeconds
            m_svcTimer.Enabled = True
            m_svcTimer.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ClassLibraries.clsUtilities.WriteLog("Failed in WaitToStart " & ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming that `sc stop` works on the target service, the most likely problem is that you can't start or stop a service from inside the start or stop routine of another service.  Try making the stop request from a separate thread.

Comment: Harry, What do you mean when you say from a separate thread?

Comment: From a thread you've created yourself, rather than the thread that is calling OnStart() or OnStop().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and I want to let future readers of this thread know about it.

Harry Johnston was on the right track suggestion a separate thread which I never hear of before. But the thread belonged in the Service I was trying to stop not the service that was doing the stopping. Because the On Start routine never ended I could stop the process programmatically. I put the bulk of what I am doing in a separate thread.